# Need to add numbers together from a file

Tags: linux

I have a file that looks like this:

```
$ cat filename.txt
112K    CDR011587024051.csv
1568K   CDR011587024052.csv
11K     CDR011587024054.csv
2789K   CDR011587024055.csv
```

I need to add just the numbers together to get my total.

Comment: Assuming you mean the numbers in the _first_ column, does the `K` signify 1000? Would there occur any other suffixes? Should the output use the same `K` unit?

Comment: yes, it does need to signify the same.

Comment: nO other suffixes.  Just the ones in the first column.  I dont need the "K" but it part of the output to the file "filename.txt"

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{print $1}' filename.txt | tr -d 'K' | awk '{SUM+=$1}END{print SUM}'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '{ sum += $1 } END { print sum }' <filename.txt
4480
```

Since the `K` unit/suffix should be thrown away, you can simply add the numbers up with `awk`.  `awk` would automatically convert the strings to numbers, throwing away everything from the first position in the string onwards that couldn't be converted.